# creating a related post script in php - Not Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, logic, blogs

I would like to know if any one has any working code that could show related blog post say about four or five based on the category of the current blog post. Note that am NOT USING wordpress or any other blogging script amd using a simple blog script i wrote in php.

My database is quite simple : : I have a table that houses all the post and a category column. so all post in the DB have a set category. I would like the script to select and return any for latest based on date submitted.

This is my current query

```
select * from post where category = '$current_blog_post_category' order by post_date desc limit 4
```

the problem with this howeve is that once the query runs it still returns the current post as a result. i would like the current post to be ignored in the query. Any work around will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select * from post
where category = '$current_blog_post_category' 
      AND post.id <> '$current_blog_post_id'
order by post_date desc limit 4
```

Please note that i suppose that 'id' is named your column that store post ids.

Comment: yes there is a column that stores post id..let me try your code i will get back to you.

Comment: thank you mate...Works just fine..and here i was thinking i could do some magic on sql queries...lol :) thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The current post supposed to have the latest id (and also post_date, but this version is more reliable, because two post can have theoretically the same post_date):

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE 
    category = '$current_blog_post_category' AND
    id!=MAX(id)
ORDER BY post_date desc 
LIMIT 4
```